# Laravel Eloquent model data from 2 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I've just started using Laravel and I'm coming from a different system using an existing database. In this system there are 2 users table, one stock with the CMS and one custom one.

I want to create an Eloquent model which retrieves data from both tables into one model. I know I can use the following to create a relationship.

`$this->hasOne('App\SecondUser', 'id', 'id);`

But this results in 2 sql queries, and I want to join results from 2 tables before returning the model, in one `join` statement. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That might be a bit more complicated that you would expect.

First of all you have to use `\DB` facade to join the two collections(arrays) and then recreate the Eloquent collection from these arrays using Collection's `make` method.

More info about the Collection class [here](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html)

An easier way might be to join them using standard laravel relationships and user something like `Model::user->with('relation')->get`.

But this will still create 2 queries (still relatively fast).